# App/Web App whose log-in with smartcard-NFC

Tags: web-applications, push-notification, nfc, smartcard, smartcard-reader

I'm doing a research on the "state of art" of the authentication using smart-card and NFC. In particular I'm focusing on web sites or web apps whose send push notification to mobile and use NFC to read the user's identity from his/her smart-ID-card.
So my question is: does anybody know any of these web app or web sites doing something like what I described above?

Answer (score 0):

Features like Web Bluetooth API and Web NFC API are experimental as of now.
Most of the platforms and browsers either don't support them or only support them under experimental features which have to be manually enabled from browser specific settings.

Browsers also show warnings while enabling them that this feature is experimental which reduces the chance of any user enabling it when a site requests them to enable it, I am just assuming it as people are getting concerned about their privacy and security.

If you want to try it for development purposes you can see following examples and docs.

http://w3c.github.io/web-nfc/ (Did not work for me on MACOS)

https://whatwebcando.today/nfc.html (Sample code for Web NFC API)

https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/device-info-async-await.html?allDevices=true&service=device_information (This worked in Chrome but requires experimental features to be enabled on Safari and Firefox)

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web

https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/master/implementation-status.md (For checking browser support)

At the time of writing this, I could not find any other way of implementing Bluetooth and NFC in websites.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for response this was very helpful even though I was actually looking for remote authentication using NFC in a smartphone. The example use-case could be: user on a laptop wants to authenticate on a site A, insert username and password and receives a push notification on the site's A app where he gives his credentials through a smartcard using NFC! If someone knows sites/apps doing something like this I will appreciate.

Comment: This should be doable, at least on Android. Security of this solution is determined by the choice of the smart card.

Comment: @IronJohn Yes, that seems to be a feasible solution, but I haven't seen a website doing that yet. Will post it here in case I find any. Thanks